# Как не отображать символы {{ }} на vue.js в первые секунды?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Во время загрузки сайта в первые секунды видны символы `{{ }}` Сайт на vue.js .
Как их скрыть?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Вам нужна использовать директиву [`v-cloak`](http://vuejs.org/api/#v-cloak), как указано в документации

```
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

<div v-cloak>
  {{ message }}
</div>
```

Когда инстанс vue будет готов, он сам уберет ее с соответствующих элементов

Comment: Спасибо. Как раз только что нашёл))))